# How to use OAuth securely on custom domains?

Tags: security, oauth, google-oauth

Our software can be installed by customers on premise. Optionally we provide predictable domain names like *.foo.eu and sometimes customers just user their own domain names.

We want to integrate our Web application installed on a customer machine with custom domain with OAuth authentication mechanisms (Google, Office365, maybe some others)

To use OAuth a customer will need to create a "project" or an "application" in specific service and set his domain as allowed.

How can we avoid it? 
Is there a way we can simplify it for a customer and register only one application though we don't know custom domain names?

What is a security reason to restrict domain names in OAuth projects?
What if we simply redirect OAuth responses from our central website to a customer domain?

Comment: Hit by the same issue. My company is a cloud solutions provider and our customers may use "vanity domains" (i.e. custom domains) for their sites hosted on our platform. In this case, how does one add their domain to our single AD app's Redirect URLs list? The number of such custom domains is very long to do this brute force.